# Difference in Hebrew of Rabbis

Tags: hebrew, rabbis

We can see that some rabbis have different way of writing sefarim. For example,  Rav Kook's writing,  people say that his Hebrew is very much different and we need a teacher for his books.

Why do Rabbis have different approaches of using Hebrew in their sefarim?  Is it not ok to use the most simple Hebrew for easier and wider grasp of the material?

Comment: Also some non rabbis have different ways of writing in all contexts. Why didn't James Joyce limit himself to the vocabulary of Simple English Wikipedia

Comment: The "issue" with R Kook is not just the Hebrew although it is true he uses complicated words. But many times what he writes is poetry rather than "normal writing" and many of his expressions are allusions to talmudic or kabbalistic concepts. I find him nearly impossible to comprehend without a teacher

Answer (score 2):

When rabbis write books, their intention is not always to make their material widely understandable. Different books have different purposes. Books aimed at beginners should certainly be written in a way that's easy to understand. But many books are written with an assumed level of prior knowledge. This allows writing to be more concise since every concept need not be explained.

This can be extended to more extreme cases. For example, writings on more esoteric topics may use jargon that is completely unfamiliar to most. If every word of jargon were to be explained, the flow of the book would be interrupted, actually making it *harder* to understand for the book's actual intended audience: those with deep knowledge in the area. These books aren't intended to be understood by a wide audience.